# Icon missing: 404 Not Found on SkyDriveIcon_blue.png

Tags: javascript, api, onedrive

My website uses the SkyDrive Javascript API to show an 'Open from SkyDrive' button (using Wl.ui). 
I noticed that the icon that used to be shown is no longer showing, I get a 404 - file not found on http://js.live.net/v5.0/images/SkyDrivePicker/SkyDriveIcon_blue.png

Has anyone seen the same issue and does anyone know how to solve it?

Some snippets:

The script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//js.live.net/v5.0/wl.js"></script>
```

The div for the button

```
<DIV ID="uploadFile_div">SkyDrive save button to appear here</DIV>
```

And the code for WL.ui

```
WL.ui({
    name: "skydrivepicker",
    element: "uploadFile_div",
    mode: "open",
    select: "single",
    onselected: onPickFileCompleted,
    onerror: onUploadFileError
});
```

The website that shows the problem is http://www.padvark.nl/index.php?page=gpxpauser

Thanks in advance,

Koen

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an issue on the OneDrive side.  We have a fix that should hopefully make it out soon.